# Compare multiple ID's and pull data from table

Tags: excel, vba, copy, compare

-How to alter this script so it compares multiple values(ID's) on Worksheet("Theorie")(A11:A17) with ("DATA")(A1),pulls values from columns B,C,D,E,H,I and J on sheet ("DATA")and copies those values to("Theorie"),destination should start at (B11)

```
 Sub Data_uit_DATA_Raadplegen()

    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rngInventory As Range

    With Worksheets("DATA")
        Set rngInventory = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    End With
    
    'vorige copie verwijderen van "Theorie"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Theorie").Range("B11:K41").ClearContents
    
    For Each rCell In rngInventory.Cells
        If (rCell.Offset(0, 9).Value) = Worksheets("Theorie ").Range("D3").Value Then 'check column J
            With Worksheets("Theorie")
                 Set rNext = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                 Set rNext = IIf(rNext.Row < 10, .Cells(10, 2), rNext)
                 
                 End With

            rCell.Resize(1, Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy
            rNext.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Are these three worksheets in the workbook containing this code? Do you need to compare the values in column `J` (`.Offset(0, 9)`) against the value in `D3`? What does `B,C,D,E,H,I and J` mean (`F` and `G` are missing)? It's certainly different than `.Resize(1, Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Columns.Count)`.  Using simple words, try to explain what needs to be copied and where to. Possibly, add the screenshots of the two 'important' worksheets (`DATA` and `Theorie`) to your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyValuesFromPraktijkToDATA()
    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rngInventory As Range
    Dim rngPraktijkIDs As Range
    Dim DATAColumnsQty As Byte: DATAColumnsQty = Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim r As Long
    With Worksheets("DATA")
        Set rngInventory = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    End With
    Set rngPraktijkIDs = Worksheets("Praktijk").Range("A11:A17")
    For Each rCell In rngInventory.Cells
        For Each rNext In rngPraktijkIDs.Cells ' compare rCell with each ID in Praktijk IDs
            If rCell.Value2 = rNext.Value2 Then
                r = rNext.Row
                With Worksheets("Praktijk")
                    Union(.Cells(r, 2), .Cells(r, 3), .Cells(r, 4), .Cells(r, 5), .Cells(r, 8), .Cells(r, 9), .Cells(r, 10)).Copy
                End With
                rCell.Offset(0, DATAColumnsQty).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next rNext
    Next rCell
'    Call Data_uit_DATA_Raadplegen
'  uncomment - Call Data_uit_DATA_Raadplegen, if you want to run SUB Data_uit_DATA_Raadplegen
'  right after this script executed
End Sub
```

Comment: It works almost like it should. Thnks, Only if I 'save' the values for a second time, new rows are used. I'd like to 'overwrite' the old data, so corrections can be made.

Comment: Hi Jop. Do you want to clean up "destination" columns on "DATA" before you add values from "Praktijk"? Or you mean that values can be change and you want just to ovewrite if new values were added to "Praktijk"? Do you have headers for "DATA"?

Comment: I'd like to overwrite them. The headers are:-Rslt Theox -Rslt Prktx -Vw53346 -Vw53283.

Comment: just to check the script behaviour, could you please change 'DATAColumnsQty = Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Columns.Count' to 'DATAColumnsQty =10' ( 10 is the number of original columns qty in DATA if I remeber it correctly) . And let me know if it's it. Then, we can make this number dependent from headers columns qty)

Comment: Behaves like it should.

Comment: Fine. Did we finish the issue, or something remains not fixed?

Comment: I'll try harder to understand how it works to determen the destination colums. With everything you helpen on I should be able to combi one and other to finish the project. I'll probably post some new questions the next days with some other issues.

Comment: You are welcome).Regarding destination columns. If you specify what exactly is unclear then I can try to give some explanation.